# Нужно создать комментарии к посту на блог в django

Tags: django

Всем привет. Хочу создавать систему комментарии к посту на моём блог сайте в django. В интернете не мог найти нормальный туториал. Можете мне помогать step by step?
Вот мой models.py:

```py
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    #text = models.TextField()
    #text = RichTextField()
    text = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    avtor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('news-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Вот views.py:

```py
class ShowNewsView(ListView):
    model = News
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'news'
    ordering = ['-date']
    paginate_by = 7

    def get_context_data(self, **kwards):
        ctx = super(ShowNewsView, self).get_context_data(**kwards)
        ctx['title'] = 'itProger.uz'
        return ctx


class UserAllNewsView(ListView):
    model = News
    template_name = 'blog/user_news.html'
    context_object_name = 'news'
    paginate_by = 7

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return News.objects.filter(avtor=user).order_by('-date')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwards):
        ctx = super(UserAllNewsView, self).get_context_data(**kwards)
        ctx['title'] = f"{ self.kwargs.get('username')}ning barcha maqolalari"
        return ctx


class NewsDetailView(DetailView):
    model = News

    def get_context_data(self, **kwards):
        ctx = super(NewsDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwards)
        ctx['title'] = News.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['pk']).first()
        return ctx
```

вот news-detail.html

```html
{% extends 'blog/main.html' %}
{% block main_section %}
    <div class="alert alert-light">
        <a href="{% url 'blog-home' %}">Asosiy sahifaga qaytish</a>
        <h1>{{ object.title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ object.text|safe }}</p>
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                {% if object.avtor.profile.img %}
                    <img src="{{ object.avtor.profile.img.url }}" alt="{{ object.avtor }}" class="user_image">
                {% else %}
                    <img src="/pictures/default.jpg" class="user_image">
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="mt-2">
                <span class="text-muted"><b>Sana: </b>{{ object.date|date:"d E Y, H:i" }}</span>
                <p><b>Muallif:</b>  <a href="{% url 'user-news' object.avtor %}">{{ object.avtor }}</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% if object.avtor == user %}
            <hr>
            <a href="{% url 'news-update' object.id %}" class="btn btn-info">Maqolani yangilash</a>
            <a href="{% url 'news-delete' object.id %}" class="btn btn-danger">Maqolani o'chirish</a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endblock main_section %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Основное отличие комментария (абстрактно) от других моделей в том, что мы не можем чётко определить его взаимосвязь с конкретной моделью, так как комментировать можно очень много всего.
Мы бы могли создать несколько моделей комментария на всё, что можно комментировать, но в `Django` есть более изящное решение.

Мы воспользуемся `GenericRelation`. Это позволит нам привязывать комментарий к любой из указанных моделей. Я для примера создам модель `Post`, а Вы можете распространить это для своей модели `News`.

***models.py:***

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey


class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=4096)


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=4096)
    comments = GenericRelation(Comment)
```

Для комментария я создал всего несколько полей - `author`, `created`, `text`.
Вы можете дополнить модель по своему усмотрению, но оставшиеся поля не трогайте. Они технические и служат для связи наших моделей, это же касается и поля `comments` у модели `Post`.

Для того чтобы создать комментарий мы можем сделать следующее:

```py
obj_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(post)
Comment.objects.create(content_type=obj_type, object_id=post.id, author=user)
```

Получить комментарии к конкретному посту можно так:

```py
Comment.objects.filter(object_id=post.id)
```

`post` - экземпляр модели `Post`.
`user` - экземпляр модели `User` (например, `request.user` в представлении).

Comment: Довольно подробное описание того, что нужно сделать

Comment: @ZaArs Спасибо, я старался :3

Comment: Кстати, в вопросе одна модель для комментариев, так что можно добавить и частный случай, когда коммент относится только к 1 модели, имхо